# Elastic Search - Aggregation by topic

Tags: elasticsearch

I have multiple topics (booleans) and I want to do aggregation on them. e.g.

```
topic A -> car AND bike
topic B -> movies AND entertainment
topic C -> (X OR Y) AND Z
```

I have big list of booleans like this categorized in the the form of topics. Each booleans are complex than shown in the above example.

No I want to show the count based on the topic using aggregation, or I want to show day-wise breakup of the data of each topic. e.g.

```
topic A -> X records
topic B -> Y records
topic C -> Z records
```

Right now I am sending individual requests to the elasticsearch to get count for each topics and then combining the output into a final array. This process takes so much time because of number of http requests involved.

Suggest me the efficient way to achieve this.

> Note : topic booleans are changeable, so we can't assign labels to the records.

Comment: Is it not possible to use the top_hits? Im quite new to ES and i do something similar to how your questions sounds using top_hits though i maybe misunderstanding your question.   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a filters aggregation and apply any arbitrary bool filter inside of it:

```
  "aggs" : {
    "My Booleans" : {
      "filters" : {
        "filters" : {
          "Topic A" :   { "bool" : { "filter" : [{ "match": { "my_prop": "car" } }, { "match": { "my_prop": "bike" } }] } }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Bool filters can be used to build arbitrarily complex filter logic as they provide AND, OR and NOT logic, and can be nested.

Answer (score 2):

You have a list of search queries and your goal is to get (only) the number of matches for each query.

For only one query this would be the [count API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html).

For more the one query at the same time you should search with "match_all" and use [filters Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html). You could also use the [Multi Search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) with size=0.